# Replicar alterações de um repositório para outro

Tags: github, repository

Eu tenho 3 repositórios que utilizam um mesmo componente. Eu gostaria de quando realizar alterações neste componente, conseguir replicar para o outro.

É possível?

Comment: Oi, @Leticia. Em que linguagem estão esses projetos dos repositórios? Java, Go, PHP...? Esses componentes seguem algum esquema de construção? Por exemplo, PSR, plug-in, add-on, é apenas uma pasta com código, ...? Nos dê mais informações. Quem sabe até o link dos repositórios do GitHub se eles forem públicos. O Github possui hooks (como gatilhos de eventos) que podem te ajudar a automatizar a replicação.

Comment: Angular,html e css. É uma navbar que é igual nos três repositórios

Comment: Não sei exatamente como estão os repositórios, mas, tente seguir o conceito para ver se faz sentido para você. Tenha essa navbar como um componente (module) em um único projeto. Empacote ele com ng-packagr e, então, publique-o no NPM. Por fim, adicione ele como dependência nos seus outros projetos. Isso é apenas conceito. Há muita coisa a ser feita como, por exemplo, instalar o ng-packagr, vc ter uma conta no NPM (provalmente vc tem), seu componente estar programado como um módulo do Angular, etc. Estou tentando ainda imaginar como está seus repos.

Answer (score 0):

Usar componentização é uma boa prática para distribuir software/código comum entre aplicações, mas não é ideal fazer isso no próprio repositório.

Um componente, que é um conjunto de código reutilizável, deve ser tratado como uma aplicação em si. Portanto, ele terá repositório próprio e um processo de compilação que deverá entregar um artefato binário.
Por isso é importante que esse artefato não quebre constantemente sua API, e quando isso for feito, que seja da maneira mais estável possível. Soltando versões que indiquem que a API será alterada, etc...

Então se no final desse processo temos um binário, este não deve ser armazenado em um repositório de código, e sim e um repositório de pacotes. Existem diversos por aí, desde os específicos, que armazenam pacotes de uma linguagem, até os chamados repositórios de pacotes universais, que estão em bastante evidência no momento.

Por exemplo:

- Proget, da Inedo, que armazena pacotes de C#/.NET (NuGet), JavaScript/NodeJS (npm), Ruby (Gems), ou Java (Maven): https://inedo.com/support/documentation/proget/feeds/nuget
- VSTS, da Microsoft, que tem gestão de pacotes iguais ao anterior, além de toda a automação do pipeline, ou seja, você pode ter o código em um repositório Git, fazer o build, e armazenar o pacote, tudo na mesma aplicação: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/index?view=vsts